# How to use a VBA to combine rows that are prematurely broken from a CSV?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a CSV showing purchase information, but in each line the data must have too many commas as a few extra breaks are added in. In this case, row 1 is the header. Rows 2-5 should be merged into one, and the blank row 6 shouldn't exist.
Here's what the data looks like in the "Get Data" feature in Excel before being input

[image]

I think the solution provided here is close to what I need to do, but as someone who's never written a Macro I was wondering if someone can provide a more specific solution.
https://superuser.com/questions/395126/how-to-combine-values-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-in-excel

Comment: If you just open the file directly in excel is it parsed correctly?

Comment: Sanitize your data before you import it. If it's not formatted correctly you should handle that at the source, not here at the end.

Comment: @Tim - Saving as an excel file or opening in excel does not display the text correctly.

Comment: @HackSlash - I'm unable to change the source and can not open the raw data. Opening in wordpress or notepad opens gibberish

Comment: @DP303030 A CSV file is just text with a comma delimiter. Opening in a basic notepad program should produce a readable file. Albiet not easy to read, but also not "gibberish". Can you post some sample data?